# Skife JDBI Insert as BLOB fails for odd length byte arrays

Tags: java, arrays, byte, jdbi

Getting this error when trying to insert a blob into mysql table using jdbi:

```
@SqlUpdate("INSERT INTO Supply_v2(id, blob) VALUES (:id, :blob)")
void newSupply(@Bind("id") long id, @Bind("blob") byte[] array) {
    System.out.println("Should NOT be printed");
}
```

This throws the following exception, which after a lot of trial and error I figured is because the byte array is not even in length. Question is how do i get this to work. I don't want to put in logic to pad / unpad bits. Its sad that jdbi is not handling this properly.

I'm using org.jdbi:jdbi:2.78.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jdbi</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbi</artifactId>
  <version>2.78</version>
</dependency>
```

Exception:

```
! com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'blob) VALUES (0, x'0A4C0800120C476167616E20636F6F6B20321A0610A8AEDCC72138014A2A0' at line 1
! at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
! at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
! at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
! at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1307)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1327)
! ... 73 common frames omitted
! Causing: org.skife.jdbi.v2.exceptions.UnableToExecuteStatementException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'blob) VALUES (0, x'0A4C0800120C476167616E20636F6F6B20321A0610A8AEDCC72138014A2A0' at line 1 [statement:"INSERT INTO Supply_v2(id, blob) VALUES (:id, :blob)", located:"INSERT INTO Supply_v2(id, blob) VALUES (:id, :blob)", rewritten:"/* CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl.newSupply */ INSERT INTO Supply_v2(id, blob) VALUES (?, ?)", arguments:{ positional:{}, named:{blob:[10, 76, 8, 0, 18, 12, 71, 97, 103, 97, 110, 32, 99, 111, 111, 107, 32, 50, 26, 6, 16, -88, -82, -36, -57, 33, 56, 1, 74, 42, 10, 7, 77, 71, 32, 82, 111, 97, 100, 18, 9, 98, 97, 110, 103, 97, 108, 111, 114, 101, 34, 0, 42, 18, 9, -94, 125, -84, -32, -73, -15, 41, 64, 17, 0, 111, -127, 4, -59, 105, 83, 64, 88, 1, 88, 2, 88, 5, 42, 37, 10, 22, 8, 10, 16, 0, 24, 11, 32, 0, 40, 1, 40, 2, 40, 3, 40, 4, 40, 5, 40, 6, 40, 7, 56, 1, 66, 9, 10, 7, 77, 71, 32, 82, 111, 97, 100, 64, 1],id:0}, finder:[]}]
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.SQLStatement.internalExecute(SQLStatement.java:1338)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.Update.execute(Update.java:56)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.UpdateHandler$2.value(UpdateHandler.java:67)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.UpdateHandler.invoke(UpdateHandler.java:79)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:224)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$3.intercept(SqlObject.java:133)
! at com.homedruid.server.dao.impl.v2.CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$17a783a7.newSupply(<generated>)
! at com.homedruid.server.dao.impl.v2.CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl.newSupply(CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl.java:87)
! at com.homedruid.server.dao.impl.v2.CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$17a783a7.CGLIB$newSupply$7(<generated>)
! at com.homedruid.server.dao.impl.v2.CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$17a783a7$$FastClassByCGLIB$$8e49c117.invoke(<generated>)
! at org.skife.jdbi.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.PassThroughHandler.invoke(PassThroughHandler.java:34)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject.invoke(SqlObject.java:224)
! at org.skife.jdbi.v2.sqlobject.SqlObject$3.intercept(SqlObject.java:133)
! at com.homedruid.server.dao.impl.v2.CustomersSupplyOrdersDaoImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$17a783a7.newSupply(<generated>)
! at com.homedruid.server.resource.v2.CustomersSupplyOrdersResource.newSupply(CustomersSupplyOrdersResource.java:102)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

My sql table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Supply_v2` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blob` longblob NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: If you can reliably reproduce this with a small snippet of code, here's their [issue tracker](https://github.com/jdbi/jdbi/issues). Although to be honest, a bug like "can't insert odd length blobs" is something that would be noticed pretty quickly, so don't start blaming the JDBI guys just yet. Try later versions of JDBI, a different MySQL driver, etc.

Comment: @Kayaman: Provided the code for the same